# Converting iPhone coordinates into something Google Maps will recognize

Tags: coordinates, software-recommendations, iphone

How do I convert iPhone coordinates into something that Google Maps recognizes?

The iPhone coordinates save in Photoshop with the pictures I take on an iPhone but the coordinates are useless in Google Maps.

Is there an existing program that can do that?

I am a photographer, not a cartographer.

Comment: the coords are searchable in google. Can you share an example of what the coords look like?

Comment: What exactly is your workflow? What do you want to do? Providing an example file would help - if it's a picture, you can fill all pixels with a single color for demonstration purpose as long as the coordinates are untouched

Comment: Did you have a look at GPS Babel https://www.gpsbabel.org/ (not affiliated)

Answer (score 1):

To convert iPhone coordinates into a format that Google Maps can recognize, you can use a tool such as the GPS Coordinate Converter (https://gps-coordinates.org/coordinate-converter.php). This tool allows you to input the iPhone coordinates in the "Decimal Degrees" format, and convert them to a variety of other formats, including the "Degrees Minutes Seconds" format, which is supported by Google Maps.

For example, if your iPhone coordinates are in the following format:

40.7128° N, 74.0060° W

You can enter them into the GPS Coordinate Converter, and choose the "Degrees Minutes Seconds" format for the output. The tool will then convert the coordinates to the following format:

40° 42' 46" N, 74° 0' 21" W

You can then copy and paste this format into the search bar in Google Maps, and it will recognize the coordinates and show the location on the map.